# Python setup.py: ask for configuration data during setup

Tags: python, pip, distutils, easy-install

I package my Python application with [PIP](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip), providing a setup.py.
During installation, I want to ask the user for several values (user name, other configuration values), these values are then saved inside the application configfile stored inside the user directory.

Is there a special PIP/distutils-way to ask for these configuration values during setup? 
Or should I just use `input` to ask the user, like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from distutils.core import setup

cfg['name'] = input("Please your username:")
cfg.save()

setup(name='appname',
      version='1.0',
      description='App Description',
      author='Author',
      author_email='author@author.net',
      packages=['mypackage'],
     )
```

Or should I leave out asking for these values, and instead let the user configure the application on the first start?

I know that all of these ways are possible, but are there any conventions or best practices for that? Or do you know of a popular Python project doing similar stuff which is a good example?

Comment: I don't think there's a 'standard' for things like this. I like to delay asking for settings until after instalation unless there are some paths that are required for the actual installation.

Comment: You should not use install phase for user interaction. If you want to ask something from the user do it when the application is run for the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setup.py provides you very primitive interface to install python packages. You can use a [config file](http://docs.python.org/distutils/configfile.html) or create some GUI installer for your application.

Another way is to build OS depended packages (deb, rpm, msi for Windows) for your application.